# WordPress query - all posts that start with a special symbol (not a-z)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a query with all posts that start with a special symbol (not a-z). A normal query where i select all posts looks like this:

```
$letter = a;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'starts_with'   => $letter,
    'post_type'     => 'artists'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    /* CONTENT */
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The starts width function is coming from the functions.php:

```
function wpse_298888_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $starts_with = esc_sql( $query->get( 'starts_with' ) );

    if ( $starts_with ) {
        $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$starts_with%'";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_298888_posts_where', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
function title_filter( $where, $wp_query ){
    global $wpdb;
    if( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'title_filter' ) ) :
    $search_term = $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term );
    $search_term = ' \'' . $search_term . '%\''; // Starts with 
    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE ' . $search_term;
    endif;
    return $where;
}
```

In your template add the following query

```
$searching = 'a'; // Get all posts with title starting with letter 'a'.
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // Change to your post type
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Change to restrict per page
    'title_filter' => $searching, // This is where our magic happens
);
$results = new WP_Query($args);
if($results->have_posts()):
    while($results->have_posts()): $results->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

"But what i need is a filter that returns all posts where the title doesnt start with a letter"

Just change your query from `LIKE` to `NOT LIKE`

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
function title_filter( $where, $wp_query ){
    global $wpdb;
    if( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'title_filter' ) ) :
    $search_term = $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term );
    $search_term = ' \'' . $search_term . '%\''; // Starts with 
    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title NOT LIKE ' . $search_term;
    endif;
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martin i have Filter to look for posts that start with a certain letter. But what i need is a filter that returns all posts where the title doesnt start with a letter.