# Wordpress query post_title and meta_value for search term

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select

Spent a day on this and for a novice I'm going around in circles unfortunately.

Let's say I'm search for the word "The Community Axminster". The words in this term should appear in *either* the post_title in the wp_posts table, or the meta_value for the meta_key 'rz_location__geo_city' in the wp_postmeta table for the associated post. **One thing to note is that the meta_key 'rz_location__geo_city' is not always present for each post_id** (Google does not always return a location in the Places API).

```
table: wp_posts
+------+----------------------------+-------------+------------+
|  ID  |         post_title         | post_status | post_type  |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+------------+
| 9465 | Vila Anna                  | publish     | rz_listing |
| 9291 | The Community Waffle House | publish     | rz_listing |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+------------+

table: wp_postmeta
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id |       meta_key        | meta_value |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------+
|   29570 |    9465 | rz_is_claimed         | 1          |
|   29571 |    9465 | rz_location__lat      | 42.9875625 |
|   29572 |    9465 | rz_location__lng      | 13.8987698 |
|   29573 |    9465 | rz_location__geo_city | Palma      |
|   29577 |    9291 | rz_is_claimed         | 1          |
|   29578 |    9291 | rz_location__lat      | 11.8976543 |
|   29579 |    9291 | rz_location__lng      | 14.9087654 |
|    2958 |    9291 | rz_location__geo_city | Axminster  |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------+
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT p.post_title, p.ID, p.post_type, p.post_status, m.post_id, m.meta_value, m.meta_key  
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} p 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} m 
        ON ( p.ID = m.post_id ) 
        WHERE p.post_type = %s 
        AND p.post_status = %s 
        AND ( ( p.post_title LIKE '%%$wordone%%' OR p.post_title LIKE '%%$wordtwo%%' ) OR ( m.meta_key = 'rz_location__geo_city' AND ( m.meta_value LIKE '%%$wordone%%' OR m.meta_value LIKE '%%$wordtwo%%' ) ) ) 
        ",
        $post_type,
        $post_status
        ) 
    );
```

The problem with this request is that if I type the word "the", I return an array of results for the same post, but I'm expecting one result. This is also true if I search for "the community axminster", "the stackoverflow". Funnily enough, if I search for "axminster anna" then I get one result for 'The Community Waffle House' plus an array of results for Vila Anna, but in actual fact I should be returning zero results. And if I search for "Palma Axminster" I get two results but I should be returning zero.

Any help much appreciated. I'm not sure if it's necessary to say this but in the query above, for simplicity, I wrote `p.post_title LIKE '%%$wordone%%' OR p.post_title LIKE '%%$wordtwo%%'` however in reality I'm taking the search term and doing the following:

```
$words = explode(' ', $search_term);
$conds = array();
foreach ($words as $val) {
    $conds[] = "p.post_title LIKE '%%".$val."%%'";

}
$implode_statement = implode(' OR ', $conds);
```

Comment: I think I have the answer, been working on this for a few more hours and seems to work now, just need to debug but I'll do that tomorrow.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209196/wordpress-query-all-posts-that-start-with-a-special-symbol-not-a-z